# BMO 2017 Round 1 problem #6

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, puzzle

> Matthew has a deck of 300 cards numbered 1 to 300. He takes cards
>   out of the deck one at a time, and places the selected cards in a row,
>   with each new card added at the right end of the row. Matthew must
>   arrange that, at all times, the mean of the numbers on the cards in
>   the row is an integer. If, at some point, there is no card remaining in
>   the deck which allows Matthew to continue, then he stops.
>   When Matthew has stopped, what is the smallest possible number of
>   cards that he could have placed in the row? Give an example of such
>   a row.

I have successfully interpreted the problem. But I am not able to proceed. 
$$k+1|x_1+x_2+...+x_k+\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the new card no.
Now we need to find the minimum value of $k$. But how?

Comment: It is an interesting question. Have you had any thoughts of your own?

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I agree with you that this is an interesting question....but I am unable to proceed without any help...would you provide any hint?

Comment: Here is a hint that at least gets you a lower bound.  Consider $s_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i$.  As long as there is some card left whose value mod $(k+1)$ is congruent to $-s_k$, then we can continue.  But how many elements are congruent to $-s_k$?  If we've used them all already, how big must $k$ be?  What if we further add in the conditions that we could have gotten to that point in the first place?

Comment: Please can anyone give a complete ans?....I am unable to solve this

Comment: @Aaron Sorry but I am unable to apply this

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, as a lower bound, you can order the first 186 cards in a greedy way: https://oeis.org/A019444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $k = 16$, and we are going to place the 17-th card, with the first 16 being $a_1, \cdots, a_{16}$. Then $a_{17}$ has to satisfy $a_{17} \equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{16}a_i \pmod{17}$. But there are at least $\lfloor \frac{300}{17}\rfloor = 17$ numbers in the range 1 to 300, in each congruent class. So you can always get up to 17 cards.

When $k = 17$, and we are going to place the 18-th card, things are different. Since $\lceil\frac{300}{18}\rceil = 17$, each congruence class modulo 18 has at most 17 cards. If all the 16 or 17 cards in that congruence class are already chosen, then you have nothing to pick.

It now remains to find a sequence of length 17 satisfying your criteria and making the 18-th card impossible. The 17 numbers has to form a complete congruence class modulo 18. And you will actually see that the sum of the 17 numbers will be a multiple of 9. This means that congruence class has to be $\equiv 0$ or $9 \pmod{18}$. There are only 16 numbers in 1 to 300 which is $\equiv 0 \pmod{18}$, and there are 17 numbers which is $\equiv 9 \pmod{18}$.

So what you have to do is to try to arrange the order of the 17 numbers $9, 27, 45, \cdots, 297$. What can you do?

Answer (score 0):

See this questions is quite interesting and there multiple ways to do this question.

> Hint: Try to take some examples and try experimenting with them so that you can observe what's happening.

Solution: You can see that if we have already picked $n-1$ cards, and the Sum of the numbers till $n-1$ card be $S$. then the $n^{th}$ card which we need to pick should be such that that $(\frac{(S+a)}{n})\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ shows the number assigned to the $n^{th}$ card.

Now, we know that $S=nk+r$; $0\leq r<n$ so from this we can say that $a$ should be of the form $a=qn-r$ $\forall$ $q=\left\{ 1,2,3,...,n\right\}$, we know that we have chosen $n-1$ cards and $a$ has $n$ number of values possible hence considering there are all values of $a$ used, but still there will exist one value of $a$ which is unused.

I would need the value of $a_{max}\leq300$ here $a_{max}=n^2-r$ Because $300$ is the highest value which I have. So from this I can say that $n^2\leq 300+r$ now as we need to find the maximum value of $n^2$ and we need to find the minimum possible value where Matthew can stop without continuing hence we can consider that $r=0$ from this I can say that $n^2\leq 300$ so the maximum $n$ which satisfies is $17$ so I need to show that there exists a string of number like this such that it stops and the $18^{th}$ card doesn't exist.

We can show this as we know the possible values of $a=18-r,2(18)-r,3(18)-r,...,17(18)-r$, if we had taken $18$ cards then the last value won't have satisfied as taking the value of $r=17$ is the maximum value of $r$, but the maximum value of $a$ won't have satisfied

Now take $r=17$ and we get the string $1, 19, 37,...,289$ having a total of 17 values